# How can i avoid calling config.php in an ajax file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am developing a web application that calls a configuration file (config.php) once, in index.php. The configuration file contains various variables that stores paths to different kinds of the application like include files, class files and so on.
However, i am using AJAX in my application but i cannot seem to access these paths through the ajax files and i do not want to call config.php again because it loads a whole lot of other things (just like Framework).
Is there anyway to include these paths without calling config.php again?

I hope i am clear. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yeah, split them to a different file you can include and include that in `config.php`. That way you can include it seperately without neede d the entire config.php file.

Answer (score 1):

You could split the "config.php" into two files - "config.php" (actual configuration) and "includes.php" (does all the other stuff).
Then in the "index.php" you could check if the request is ajax or a regular one and include one or both files. To detect if it is a full page load or an ajax request, use this tutorial: http://davidwalsh.name/detect-ajax

Answer (score 0):

can't you set your ajax endpoint as a route that goes via index.php. alternativly rip out the config stuff and put into a speperate file that including in a setup.php that does the framework stuf.